# Incorrrect Date Format on Blog Posts

Tags: blog, date-time, mysite

I have a SharePoint 2013 On-Premises farm, and the regional settings are set to 'Ireland' (for which date format is dd/mm/yyyy). If I create a Blog Post in my personal site on 6th Jan 2014, it shows up under the Blog post Title as 1st June 2014, even though in the Posts library I can see it thinks correctly that the post was modified on 6th Jan.

If I create a post on 19th June, it will not show the date at all (19/06/2014). Somewhere between the storing and the displaying of the date it seems to be assuming a US Date (mm/dd/yyyy), and being confused when it gets a date that is obviously not a correct US Date.

Interestingly this only seems to happen on users MySite Blogs (which have not been customised at all), and not on a Blog site set up on the Intranet.

Does anybody know what is going on and what could be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guru,
I have resolved the issue (I think).
I went into 'Site Settings -> Regional Settings' on the Blog site of the users personal site. They were all set to English (Ireland) by default. I changed it to the Region the user is from (English (United States), English (Australia) etc.), and the Blog Dates now came out in the correct interpretation.

I guess because it interprets the dates in the format you put them in as, which is picked up from the culture you have set?

But the bottom line seems to be:
Set the My Site Regional Settings for where the user is located, not where the Head Office is located.

Answer (score 0):

Check time zone in 'My Regional Settings' not in user profile - hope that helps

Comment: Time Zone didn't help, but setting the Regional Settings on the Blog Site did.